# Rails error on migration, rake aborted

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have this migration to the table users made with Devise, all worked fine until i tried to make a back office with active_admin gem and added a role, etc:

```
 class DeviseCreateUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table(:users) do |t|
    ## Database authenticatable
    t.string :username,           null: false, default: ""
    t.string :email,              null: false, default: ""
    t.string :encrypted_password, null: false, default: ""


    ## Recoverable
    t.string   :reset_password_token
    t.datetime :reset_password_sent_at

    ## Rememberable
    t.datetime :remember_created_at

    ## Trackable
    t.integer  :sign_in_count, default: 0, null: false
    t.datetime :current_sign_in_at
    t.datetime :last_sign_in_at
    t.string   :current_sign_in_ip
    t.string   :last_sign_in_ip

    ## Confirmable
    t.string   :confirmation_token
    t.datetime :confirmed_at
    t.datetime :confirmation_sent_at
    t.string   :unconfirmed_email # Only if using reconfirmable


    t.timestamps


    end

    add_index :users, :email,                unique: true
    add_index :users, :username,             unique: true
    add_index :users, :reset_password_token, unique: true
    add_index :users, :confirmation_token,   unique: true
    # add_index :users, :unlock_token,         unique: true
  end
end
```

And this migration that add a column to the table:

```
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
      add_column :users, :role, :string

      User.create! do |u|
          u.username  = 'admin'
          u.email     = 'admin@example.com'
          u.password    = 'admin123'
          u.role = 'administrator'
      end
  end
end
```

I do rake db:migrate and got this error:

```
rake aborted!
StandardError: An error has occurred, this and all later migrations      canceled:

Record invalido/home/dev8/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-  4.2.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:79:in `raise_record_invalid'
/home/dev8/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/validations.rb:43:in `save!'
/home/dev8/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/attribute_methods/dirty.rb:29:in `save!'
/home/dev8/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `block in save!'
/home/dev8/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord- 4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:347:in `block in  with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/dev8/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:211:in `transaction'
/home/dev8/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:220:in `transaction'
/home/dev8/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:344:in `with_transaction_returning_status'
/home/dev8/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/transactions.rb:291:in `save!'
/home/dev8/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/persistence.rb:51:in `create!'           /home/dev8/RedTwitter/db/migrate/20150605140226_add_role_to_users.rb:6:in `change'
/home/dev8/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:606:in `exec_migration'
/home/dev8/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:590:in `block (2 levels) in migrate'
/home/dev8/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/migration.rb:589:in `block in migrate'
/home/dev8/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.1/gems/activerecord-4.2.1/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in `with_connection'
........
```

I tried rake db:rollback and got a similar error.
What could it be?

EDIT:
User.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
     :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,      :registerable, :confirmable, :authentication_keys => [:login]
 attr_accessor :login
 has_many :tweets , dependent: :destroy
 validates :username,
   :presence => true,
   :uniqueness => {
   :case_sensitive => false
    }, length: { in: 6..20 }


  def role?(role)
     roles.include? role.to_s
  end

  def login=(login)
     @login = login
  end

  def login
     @login || self.username || self.email
  end

  def self.find_for_database_authentication(warden_conditions)
      conditions = warden_conditions.dup
      if login = conditions.delete(:login)
      where(conditions.to_hash).where(["lower(username) = :value OR  lower(email) = :value", { :value => login.downcase }]).first
      else
        where(conditions.to_hash).first
      end
  end
```

end

Comment: your migration off adding a column to the table of users is throwing validation error and that is why your migrations are failing

Comment: but why is throwing validation errors?

Comment: add user.rb in your post..

Comment: from model or from admin ?

Comment: username has validations of length from 6..20.. So that is why it is giving error

Comment: the user you're creating in the test is invalid. Use `create` instead of `create!` and check the errors on the user to see why.

Comment: In addition to what @test pointed out about the length, it's possible that the username already exists in your table, and you are validating uniqueness...

Comment: it worked, thks. username less than 6 chars :p

Comment: how it worked for less than 6 characters?

Comment: it had less than 6 chars , now it has more so it works

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need to call `User.reset_column_information` in your migration, after adding the new column, otherwise Rails doesn't know about it.

Comment: your point is right..but before going to role, the error is occurring and if that would be the error then the message would be undefined method role.

Answer (score 0):

```
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration

  def change
      add_column :users, :role, :string
      User.reset_column_information
      u = User.new
      u.username  = 'admin'
      u.email     = 'admin@example.com'
      u.password    = 'admin123'
      u.role = 'administrator'
      u.save(:validate => false)
  end
end
```

Comment: That (potentially) fixes the symptom, but not the problem. Arbitrarily turning off validation can lead to bad data. It may lead to an error at the DB level as well, although if there aren't any DB constraints as appears the case here, it won't.

Comment: this is a migration and for creation of one record we can do that and it is not a bad practice.. If we have written this in code then it would be bad but for migration I don't think so it is bad because migration will execute once

Answer (score 0):

Use [find or create](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.0.2/ActiveRecord/Relation/first_or_create) method. This will allow you to not raise invalid record error if you already have user, so all later migrations will run well.